# Is there a way to set the width of all td's in the same column without doing it manually for each td?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set the width of all td's in the **same column** without doing it manually for each td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:first-child` and `+` to get the column you want:

```
td:first-child { }                  /* Column 1 Styles */
td:first-child + td { }             /* Column 2 Styles */
td:first-child + td + td { }        /* Column 3 Styles */
td:first-child + td + td + td { }   /* Column 4 Styles */
```

This works in older browsers that don't support `nth-child(n)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [HTML `<col>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp):

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <col class='first-col' />
  <col />
  <col />
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
</table>

.first-col {background:red; /*add width or any other styling here*/ }
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KJhY5/2/)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for you

```
tr td:first-child {
    width:100px;
}
```

You could always give all the `<td>`'s in a particular column a class, like `<td class="column3">` which would simplify things greatly:

```
.column3 {
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Provided he only wants the first column, then yes this works. But if he wants to select other columns this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the width of one cell in a column, all the cells in that column will have that width too.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. That's the problem with tables that it takes the width of the widest `td` element for the whole column.

Comment: @Adrian: well, yes. So just set the width for one of the cells. (I guess you don’t have control over the HTML?)

Comment: Not sure you understood my comment or I don't understand your comment. ;) Somebody even downvoted my upvote on your answer. :(

Comment: @Adrian: yeah, I am a bit confused about what you’re asking. You said you want to set the width of all cells in a column, without manually assigning a width to each cell in the column. Well, setting the width of one cell in a column *does* set the width of all cells in that column. Your comment says that the width of the widest cell sets the width for the column. Yup. So just set the width on one cell.

Comment: I wasn't asking, just commenting, supporting your answer because the other answers are not wrong but the :first-child pseudo-class is not necessary.

Comment: @Adrian: oh I know, and I appreciate it. When I said I wasn’t sure what you were asking, I meant your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure changing the width of a cell in one column does it for the rest of them. If that doesn't work, I would give them all a class and style the class. Hope this helps, it's my first answer.